# DFS File shares intermittently unavailable

Tags: dns, active-directory

Just started working a new job and they have an issue that so far has completely stumped me.

Certain file shares seem to become unavailable intermittently.

\\domainname\FileShares\ returns unavailable, meanwhile all the below work.

1. \\DC1\FileShares
2. \\DC2\FileShares
3. \\DC3\FileShares
4. \\DC4\FileShares
5. \\MemberServer\FileShares

I went through all six of our DNS servers and did a lookup on all four of the DC's and domainanme. All returned the expected results.

There are multiple folders in the same namespace and one folder seems to have issues more than the others. The only setting different I found was the the "Override referral ordering was set to be "Last among all targets" I have since unchecked that and the issue persists.

***Edit: Also we only have the one default site in Active Directory Sites and Services.

If anyone has any ideas I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

•   As you said, you have unchecked the option of ‘Override referral ordering’ in DFS management for domain-based namespace, rather than unchecking it, please select the ‘First among all targets’ option as this will redirect all requests to access a domain-based network share, i.e., ‘\domainname\fileshares\’ always and prioritize them.

•   Also, please check the GPO for mapped network drives in ‘User Configuration --> Preferences --> Windows Settings --> Drive Maps’, in that check the mapped network drives and their properties whether their action is set to ‘Replace’ or ‘Update’. If the action is set to ‘Replace’, then change it to ‘Update’ and then let the GPO to be applied to all the systems once again and if it is ‘Update’, then check the path of the network drive stated in it.

•   Ensure that the GPO ‘User Configuration --> Administrative Templates --> Shared Folders --> Allow DFS roots to be published --> Enabled’ and ‘Allow shared folders to be published --> Enabled’. Also, please check the time synchronization is accurate between all the sites of the domain.

Please refer this link given below for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/dfsn-access-failures

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I confirmed that we have set the options you suggested. I believe I am tracking it down. All instances with the issue have come from laptops with our laptop GPO applied. This sets a bunch a of offline file settings. Reviewing those.

Comment: Ok sure, please also check the eventvwr logs to get some more insight into it whether which services are being stopped or any incidents are being caused.